# ASP.Net Core different web.config by environment

Tags: asp.net-core, web-config

In ASP.Net Core, I can have different application settings for different environments by supplying multiple appsettings.<EnvironmentName>.json files. But how can I have different web.config files for different environments?

Comment: ASP.Net Core doesn't use web.config files. What config do you want to change?

Comment: Thanks @DavidG. I need web.config not for ASP.Net Core per se, but for the IIS I'm deploying to. My environments need slightly different IIS settings.

Comment: once you have deployed a web.config file to production, you could then just exclude it from publishing so the dev copy never overwrites it

Comment: @JoeAudette our environments are not static. They are all in AWS (except dev on dev machines) and get rebuilt on every deployment using CloudFormation scripts, so the whole web server gets recreated from scratch. Also it's not just dev and prod, we have at least 4 environments: dev, test, UAT, prod.

Comment: here is the open issue on github for that https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2019

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Finally after seeking on the web, i conclude web.config is considered obsolete for ASP.NET Core (Middleware approach).
In fact what you want to do with WEB.CONFIG (for IIS) should be done with ASP.NET Core **app.config** or by custom Middlewares (new philosophy so).

In my case i had to put in my web.config (only for my PRODUCTION environment which has SSL) the section below:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Since WEB.CONFIG is obsolete (of course you still can use it) for ASP.NET Core. You have to use app.config or the Middleware approach (both could be complementary). Here a sample of what i did to replace my web.config by Middleware code.

In the Startup.cs (this file is your project root), you to have to register your custom Middleware - just add 1 line (**app.UseMyCustomMiddleware**) as below:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{    
    ...
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
      ...
    }
    else
    {
      ...            
      app.UseMyCustomMiddleware();
    }
    ...
}
```

The implementation of **MyCustomMiddleware** classes should like this (i put 2 classes in the same file just for clarity):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyWeb  // Change this name to match your project name if needed
{
    public static class MyCustomMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyCustomMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            return app.UseMiddleware<MyCustomMiddleware>();
        }
    }
    public class MyCustomMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public MyCustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            this._next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            // Put your code here (at my concern, i need the code below)
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload");

            // Very important
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope my explanation and my sample could help you.